# Query to return the lowest SUM of values over X consecutive days

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm not even sure how to word this one!...

I have a table with two columns, Price (double) and StartDate (Date). I need to be able to query the table and return X number of rows, lets say 3 for this example - I need to pull back the 3 rows that have consecutive dates e.g. 7th, 8th, 9th of May 2019 which have the lowest sum'd price values from a date range.

I'm thinking a function which takes startDateRange, endDateRange, duration.

It'll return a number of rows (duration) between startDateRange and endDateRange and those three rows when sum'd up would be the cheapest (lowest) sum of any number of rows within that date range for consecutive dates.

So as an example, if I wanted the cheapest 3 dates from between 1st May 2019 and 14th May 2019, the highlighted 3 rows would be returned;

[image]

I think possibly LEAD() and LAG() might be a starting point, but I'm not really a SQL person, so not sure if there's a better way around this.

I've developed some c# on my business layer to do this currently, but over large datasets its a bit sluggish - it would be nice to get a list of records straight from my data layer.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is cheapest calculated? average of three consecutive rows?

Comment: I'm on SQL Server Management Studio 2014 at the moment @jarlh.

Comment: andomar has pretty much cracked what I'm after with his query @salman-a, just trying to understand the query a bit better in my dbms now to break it down into 3 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate averages over 3 days with a window function.  Then use `top 1` to pick the set of 3 rows with the lowest average:

```
select  top 1 StartDt
,       AvgPrice
from    (
        select  StartDt
        ,       avg(Price) over (order by StartDt rows between 2 preceding 
                                 and current row) AvgPrice
        ,       count(*) over (order by StartDt rows between 2 preceding
                               and current row) RowCnt
        from    prices
        ) sets_of_3_days
where   RowCnt = 3  -- ignore first two rows
order by
        AvgPrice desc
```

Comment: Ooooh! That's pretty much what I'm after, thanks very much - I've swapped avg(Price) for sum(Price) - that gets me one record with the total of X days. There is one snag though, it brings one row with the total price for the 3 cheapest consecutive days... i.e. May 12th 2019 : £1531 (sum'd of 480,510,541) - is there a way to pull back the three rows individually (row 10, 11, 12 from my screenshot?) thanks again! Never used the preceding command or anything like that!

Comment: this solution does not consider whether dates are consecutive only if rows are consecutive. proof? update date of day 10 to date 9 and run this procedure

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution, the logic starts when you start to declare the dates. All the best.

```
--table example
declare @laVieja table (price float,fecha date  )

insert into @laVieja values (632,'20150101')
insert into @laVieja values (649,'20150102')
insert into @laVieja values (632,'20150103')
insert into @laVieja values (607,'20150104')
insert into @laVieja values (598,'20150105')
insert into @laVieja values (624,'20150106')
insert into @laVieja values (641,'20150107')
insert into @laVieja values (598,'20150108')
insert into @laVieja values (556,'20150109')
insert into @laVieja values (480,'20150110')
insert into @laVieja values (510,'20150111')
insert into @laVieja values (541,'20150112')
insert into @laVieja values (634,'20150113')
insert into @laVieja values (634,'20150114')
-- end of setting up table example





--declaring dates
declare @fechaIni date, @fechaEnds date 
set @fechaIni = '20150101'
set @fechaEnds = '20150114'

--assigning order based on price
select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by price) as unOrden
into #laVieja
from @laVieja
where fecha between @fechaIni and @fechaEnds 

-- declaring variables for cycle 
declare @iteracion float = 1 ,@iteracionMaxima float, @fechaPrimera date, @fechaSegunda date, @fechaTercera date
select @iteracionMaxima = max(unOrden) from #laVieja


--starting cycle
while(@iteracion <= @iteracionMaxima)
begin

        --assigning dates to variables 
        select @fechaPrimera = fecha from #laVieja where unOrden = @iteracion 
        select @fechaSegunda = fecha from #laVieja where unOrden = @iteracion + 1 
        select @fechaTercera = fecha from #laVieja where unOrden = @iteracion + 2 

        --comparing variables 
        if(@fechaTercera = DATEADD(day,1,@fechaSegunda) and @fechaSegunda = DATEADD(day,1,@fechaPrimera))
        begin 

            select * from #laVieja
            where unOrden in (@iteracion,@iteracion+1,@iteracion+2)

        set @iteracion = @iteracionMaxima
        end 

set @iteracion +=1
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, yeah I think my explanation is confusing! It needs to have consecutive days, this would give me the 3 cheapest days but they wouldn't necessarily be consecutive (e.g. 11th, 12th, 13th). Cheers

Comment: Hi jezorama, all you need to do is to set the limits of the code by assigning a start date and an end date. The query should return the 3 lowest values given that dates are consecutive.

Comment: Great, thanks, this is doing exactly what I'm after - looks a little more complex than @andomar's solution - I'll give it a blast now. I get to learn some spanish with my SQL too :D

Comment: haha that's the side effect of the code, as well :) Glad it serves the purpose.

Comment: This helps me get my head around what I was originally asking for - I think I'll end up going with @andomar as it can be more dynamic based on the quantity of rows I want to SUM. Thanks again

Comment: select  top 1 StartDt
,       AvgPrice
from    (
        select  StartDt
        ,       sum(Price) over (order by StartDt rows between 2 preceding 
                                 and current row) AvgPrice
        ,       count(1) over (order by StartDt rows between 2 preceding
                               and current row) RowCnt
        from    #laVieja2
        ) sets_of_3_days
where   RowCnt = 3  -- ignore first two rows
order by
        AvgPrice

Comment: I just realized that the other solutions that you preferred over mine do not evaluate if days are consecutive. You can prove my statement by changing the dates. They only evaluate that they are in order, for example days 7,8 and 10 would be the same for them if they were 7,8 and 9. So, my solution still wins :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions with `OVER (... ROWS BETWEEN)` clause to calculate the sum/average over specific number of rows. You can then use `ROW_NUMBER` to find the other two rows.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *
         , SUM(Price) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS wsum
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS rn
    FROM #t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 rn
    FROM cte1
    WHERE rn > 2
    ORDER BY wsum, Date
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1
WHERE rn BEtWEEN (SELECT rn FROM cte2) - 2 AND (SELECT rn FROM cte2)
```

In the above query, replace *2* with *the size of window - 1*.

Comment: phwoaaarrrr. Epic. I was doing some horrible IN clause based on dates and prices to get a list of the 3 rows I wanted from the SUM'd row but clearly, I should stay away from SQL as this is how you do it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to make the number value dynamic within this section: "ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING" i.e. the number '2'? I can't seem to replace that 2 value with a variable. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like i'll have to build up the SQL dynamically from looking around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695746/dynamic-row-range-when-calculating-moving-sum-average-using-window-functions-sq

Comment: You could use correlated sub queries, or perhaps cross apply. But those would be poor performer.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91bdbb1a567bf2bfacf7eb3b188b15fe

Comment: this solution does not consider whether dates are consecutive only if rows are consecutive. proof? update date of day 10 to date 9 and run this procedure