# Running Javascript UDF on entire field in BigQuery

Tags: javascript, sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I would like to do a rolling average of a field with the window of varying length depending on other characteristics of the data. This rules out a SQL window function. What I thought I could do is just write a JavaScript UDF to compute the rolling average with a variably sized window. The rolling window would, however, require the values from the field of the size of the window. What would be the best way to do this? Or maybe I do not need javascript at all?

Example: I have a table someData:

```
Day Value

1   3.5
2   5
3   7
4   10
5   12
.   .
.   .
.   .
100 15
```

and I want to compute the rolling average of Value, with a window of variable size x. So when x = 2, my expected result would be:

```
Rolling Average 
3.5 
4.25
6
8.5
11
.
.
.
```

**Update:**

If I used a fixed number like 2 instead of a variable x I could just use a window function. The problem is that I want the number to vary, depending on e.g. days. So let's say we define x by

```
(CASE WHEN MAX(day) > 99 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS x
```

I realise now the question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695746/dynamic-row-range-when-calculating-moving-sum-average-using-window-functions-sq).

What I could simply do is:

```
(CASE WHEN MAX(day) > 99 THEN AVG(value) OVER(ORDER BY day RANGE   BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
    ELSE AVG(value) OVER(ORDER BY day RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) END)
    AS rolling_average
```

Comment: reverse engineering not working code usually does not help much or even at all - so, please show us example of your data and expected result. and also explain the logic you want.

Comment: I removed the javascript UDF / SQL attempt and expanded the description. Hope it is clear now what I mean.

Comment: what is wrong with just simple `AVG(value) OVER(ORDER BY day RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) rolling_average`? have you tried? this just gives you 2-days rolling average!

Comment: Updated the original question, turns out it had already been answered.